# Using Magento events with Mage::app('')

Tags: php, events, magento, magento-1.5

I'm trying to get a simple event observer working but I don't know if it is even possible under these circumstances.  Ultimately, I'd like to fire an event when Shipworks pushes order updates.  I think because Shipworks is done entirely in their `shipworks3.php` script and doesn't call `Mage::run()` to initialize the full store (it uses `Mage::app('')`, the observers aren't attached to the events...at least that's my going theory at this point.  However, I can't seem to get it to work.

Below is some sample code I threw together to test this out.  Please let me know if you have any thoughts on this

## EXAMPLE

First, I created a simple module with an observer and a frontend controller for testing purposes:

### config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <VPS_Test>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </VPS_Test>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <vps_test>
                <class>VPS_Test_Model</class>
            </vps_test>
        </models>
    </global>
    <events>
        <test_event_one>
            <observers>
                <test_event_one>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>VPS_Test_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>foo_test_global</method>
                </test_event_one>
            </observers>
        </test_event_one>
    </events>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <test_event_one>
                <observers>
                    <test_event_one>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>VPS_Test_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>foo_test_front</method>
                    </test_event_one>
                </observers>
            </test_event_one>
        </events>
        <routers>
            <vps_test>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>VPS_Test</module>
                    <frontName>vpstest</frontName>
                </args>
            </vps_test>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

### Observer.php

```
class VPS_Test_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function foo_test_front(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        echo "foo_test event caught in observer FRONT";
    }


    public function foo_test_global(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        echo "foo_test event caught in observer GLOBAL";
    }
}
```

### Module Config XML

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <VPS_Test>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core />
            </depends>
        </VPS_Test>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Next, to test this, I loaded `http://my_domain/vpstest` in my browser and I saw the expected output (i.e., it dispatched the event and my observer caught it)

I then created `eventtest.php` in the root of my site and hit that from my browser.  In this case, Magento did fire the event, but my observer didn't catch it.

### eventtest.php

```
require 'app/Mage.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('html_errors', 1);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


try {
    Mage::app('');

    echo "event test<br/>";

    $foo = Mage::getModel('vps_test/observer');

    echo get_class($foo) . '<br />';

    Mage::dispatchEvent('test_event_one', array('object' => ''));
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo "exception<br/>$e";
}
```

So....what am I NOT doing?  Is it even possible to use the Magento event system without the full Magento app running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typos will get you every time.  In my config.xml, I had the `<events>...</events>` block *outside* the `<global>...</global>` block.  Whoops...  Fixing that fixed my problem.

It's important to note that in this case, the **global** *area* is the only area loaded by default.  So to attach my event observer to an event when you're just running `Mage::app('')`, you need to put it in the `<global>...</global>` section.  Conversely, I believe WebFlakeStudio's answer should work, though I haven't tested it.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include following lines to make it work:

```
Mage::getConfig()->loadEventObservers($scope);
Mage::app()->addEventArea($scope);
```

Where `$scope` value can be `frontend` or `adminhtml`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need this:

```
<depends>
            <Mage_Core />
</depends>
```

in your module config.